# How to convert my existing Framework Soap Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, .net-4.0, .net-6.0

I have an existing SOAP asmx application developed with .NET Framework 4.0. The application was deployed then and it's still being used.

Now I have .NET Core 6 with Visual Studio 2022 installed on my system, and I'm unable to even open the application in Visual Studio 2022.

I don't want to use WCF (as I said, the existing SOAP service is being used).

How do I upgrade from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET Framework 4.8 or any other higher version so that it will still maintain `.asmx` and the user will not have any issue?

Comment: As noted, either web methods in a existing page, or web methods in a asmx page supports out of the box a SOAP call, a ajax + jQuery web method call (with json), or even a REST call. All 3 will work, and work without in most cases requiring any changes to your code. To upgrade from 4.0 to 4.8? You in near 99% of cases can probably just change the target framework from 4.0 to 4.8. However, you of course need to install the webforms features in VS - see my post below on how to do this.,

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be there are 2 questions here.

the first part, is making sure you have the older .net framework installed, and also install the webforms workflows for Visual Studio.

(if you don't install the work flows and bits and parts for vs to work with webforms, then you can't really open such projects and work on them).

So, from vs2022, go  tools->get tools and features.

You need to select these options - they are NOT installed by defualt:

[image]

So, after installing above, then you can (and should) be able to open that project. (note the arrows - but ALSO do check all the other options selected in above screen cap)

You need/want to get that stuff installed, and that should let you open + build the project. Get all of that buttoned up first.

***I should point out that by "default" a soap web method OUT of the box, without changes supports a REST call, and supports use of json. it ALSO without ANY changes supports a jQuery ajax call, and again does so WITHOUT any change to the EXISTING web methods you place in a web page, or say a separate asmx page. Those existing web methods also support out of the box json and REST endpoint calls - and do so without changes - but they will continue to support SOAP calls also!!!). In other words, there is not a need to change, or modify nor upgrade those existing web methods***

However, first step is to get the required bits and parts and vs workflows installed.

and, having stated the above?

There is no automated migration from .net webforms applications to say using .net core - you have to continue to use such projects as asp.net framework applications. As such, these projects are fully supported in vs2022.